# How to test a grail service that has resultTransformer within withCriteria(Spock).?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

In the below class, I just need `RevShareFormula.withCriteria` to return a result,
but getting the exception in `resultTransformer()` method.

Can anyone tell me how to Mock the below method so that i get some result from `withCriteria`

Here is the class:

```
class PartnerFinancialService {

def getPartnerPayeeRevenuShareDetails(long partnerPayeeId, def contextTypeCode) {

def partnerPayeesRevShareFormula = RevShareFormula.withCriteria {
  resultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
  createAlias('partnerRevShareConfig', 'partnerRevShareConfig')
  createAlias('pricingModel', 'pricingModel')
  createAlias('partnerRevShareConfig.revshareCategory', 'revshareCategory')
  and {
    eq("revshareCategory.payeeProfileId", partnerPayeeId)
    eq("revshareCategory.referenceContextTypeCode", contextTypeCode)
    isNull("partnerRevShareConfig.revshareValidToDate")
  }

  projections {
    property("id", "formulaId")
    property("pricingModel.id", "pricingModelId")
    property("pricingModel.pricingName", "pricingName")
    property("pricingModel.pricingType", "pricingType")
    ..
    ..
   }
}    
}
```

Here is the test class

```
@TestFor(PartnerFinancialService)
@Mock(RevShareFormula)
class PartnerFinancialServiceSpec extends Specification {

void "test getPartnerPayeeRevShareDetails"() {
def partnerPayeeRevShare = new PartnerRevShareConfig()
    partnerPayeeRevShare.id = 1
    def revShareModel = new PricingModel();
    revShareModel.id = 1
    def partnerPayeeRevShareFormula = new RevShareFormula();
    partnerPayeeRevShareFormula.id=5
    partnerPayeeRevShareFormula.pricingModel = revShareModel
    partnerPayeeRevShareFormula.partnerRevShareConfig = partnerPayeeRevShare
    partnerPayeeRevShareFormula.revshareFormula = "revshare*10"
    partnerPayeeRevShareFormula.revshareTierHighValue = 0
    partnerPayeeRevShareFormula.revshareTierLowValue= 0 

    RevShareFormula.metaClass.static.withCriteria = {partnerPayeeRevShareFormula}

    when:
    def result = service.getPartnerPayeeRevenuShareDetails(1,"PKG")
    then:
    //assert result.pricingModel.id == 1
    println "Succesfully Fetched from DB"
} 
}
```

Getting the following exception.

```
<testcase classname="com.orbitz.dat.partners.PartnerFinancialServiceSpec" name="test getPartnerPayeeRevShareDetails" time="0.039">
<error message="No signature of method: com.orbitz.dat.partners.PartnerFinancialService.resultTransformer() is applicable for argument types: (org.hibernate.transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer) values: [org.hibernate.transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer@3632aa4]" type="groovy.lang.MissingMethodException">groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.orbitz.dat.partners.PartnerFinancialService.resultTransformer() is applicable for argument types: (org.hibernate.transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer) values: [org.hibernate.transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer@3632aa4]
    at com.orbitz.dat.partners.PartnerFinancialService.$tt__getPartnerPayeeRevenuShareDetails_closure24(PartnerFinancialService.groovy:39)
    at grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.invokeClosureNode(CriteriaBuilder.java:1093)
    at grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(CriteriaBuilder.java:314)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withCriteria_closure11(GormStaticApi.groovy:304)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:302)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:37)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withCriteria(GormStaticApi.groovy:303)
    at com.orbitz.dat.partners.PartnerFinancialService.$tt__getPartnerPayeeRevenuShareDetails(PartnerFinancialService.groovy:38)
    at com.orbitz.dat.partners.PartnerFinancialServiceSpec.test getPartnerPayeeRevShareDetails(PartnerFinancialServiceSpec.groovy:71)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an integration test. Never test ORM code with unit tests. I know it's slower and the experience is less enjoyable, but you are fooling yourself if you think that you are actually testing something related to database queries with this test. You are testing the testing framework of grails (the in-memory GORM implementation)